# Scroll to specific position in for each array with view appears SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of data which is retrieved once the view appears. I'm not sure how to scroll to a specific position of this array when the view loads using scrollviewreader. How should I implement this functionality?

Main View

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        
        HStack{
            ForEach(self.data){i in
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                        VStack(spacing: 15) {
                            
                            if i.name == "" {
                                Indicator.Continuous(color: dopplePurple)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            } else {
                             
                                ZStack{
                        
                                    LastSnippetRow(refSnippet: i, refreshData: self.refresh, showBanner: $showBanner, showExpiredBanner: $showExpiredBanner, bonId: bonId)
                         
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        

                    }
                 
                }
                .padding(.top, 15)
                
                .tag(Int(i.tag))
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            proxy.scrollTo(2)
        }
    }
        
       
    
}
```

My data model

```
struct FeedModel: Identifiable {
    var id : String
    var name : String
    var snippet : SnippetModel
    var snippetId : String
    var show : Bool
    var type : String
    var tag : Int
    var time : Double
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, change `.tag(Int(i.tag))` to `.id(i.tag)`